# How to bring back Archipack measurement diagram when I click other tools?

Tags: materials, interface, archipack-add-on

I'm building a wall using mesh Archipack and the measurement diagram disappears every time I click other tools. How to bring it back?

Answer (score 3):

Select your object, then press "N" to display right panel of 3d view, find "Archipack" tab, and press "Manipulate" on top of this tab.